# Finding simpler formula

Tags: logic

I have to find simpler formula to this one:
$$\lnot(p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$
I started by using De Morgan's law to get: $$(\lnot p \lor \lnot \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$ then used the Double negation law to get: $$(\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$
Probably I am missing something because right now it seems it cannot go further. Thanks.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to find simpler formula to this one:
>
> > `not(p and not q) or (not p and q)`.
>
> I started by using De Morgan's law to get `(not p or not not q) or (not p and q)`, then used the Double negation law to get `(not p or q) or (not p and q)`.
>   Probably I am missing something because right now it seems it cannot go further. Thanks.

So far, it is good.

Associativity gives `not p or (q or (not p and q))`

Commutativity gives `not p or (q or (q and not p))`

Absorption gives `not p or q`

That is all.

---

Absorption : `A or (A and B)` means either `A` is true or both `A` and `B` are; which certainly means `A` is true.  Converserly `A` means either `A` is true or both `A` and something else is true.  So `A or (A and B)` is equivalent to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

If A follows p and B follows q then

${(A \cap B)}' \cup (A' \cap B) = A' \cup B' \cup (A' \cap B) = A' \cup B'$

since $A' \cap B \subset A' \cup B'$.

Answer (score 0):

You have four different cases: $p$ true and $q$ true, $p$ true and $q$ false, $p$ false and $q$ true, $p$ and $q$ both false. Then
\begin{align}
& p \mbox{ true and }q \mbox{ true implies } \lnot p \mbox{ or } \lnot q \mbox{ false, } \lnot p \mbox{ and } q \mbox{ false } \\
& p \mbox{ true and }q \mbox{ false implies } \lnot p \mbox{ or } \lnot q \mbox{ true, } \lnot p \mbox{ and } q \mbox{ false } \\
& p \mbox{ false and }q \mbox{ true implies } \lnot p \mbox{ or } \lnot q \mbox{ true, } \lnot p \mbox{ and } q \mbox{ true } \\
&p \mbox{ false and }q \mbox{ false implies } \lnot p \mbox{ or } \lnot q \mbox{ true, } \lnot p \mbox{ and } q \mbox{ false.} 
\end{align}
Hence $\lnot (p \mbox{ and } q) \mbox{ or } (\lnot p \mbox{ and } q)$ is false when both $p$ and $q$ are true, true in the other cases. Thus is equivalent to $q \rightarrow \lnot p$, which is false when both $p$ and $q$ are true and true in the other cases. You can also rewrite it as $\lnot q \mbox{ or } \lnot p$, which is $\lnot (p \mbox{ and } q)$.

Answer (score 0):

`not(p and q) or (not p and q)`

= (PQ)'+ P'Q

= P' + Q' + P'Q `[Applying De Morgan's 2nd Law]`

= P' (1 + Q) + Q' `[X + 1 = 1]`

= P' + Q' (Ans)

I hope I'm correct. Checked using a truth table.